# Problem while running the Multiple Script(IE Test Suite) in selenium 2.0 dotnet

Tags: selenium-rc

I am using Selenium dotnet 2.0b1 dll in my project..

if we start running the multiple script(IE Test Suite)...if any object was not found for

example if i am selection india from country dropdown..if the india is not found...it stops in that script and throws the "exception" and by the time the error is not reflecting in HTML result (we have html reports integrated with

this framework) and the other scripts are not running...
But it is not generating as HTML...

our req is if any testscript failes also the next script must execute.....

Is this problem with dll i have used selenium 2.0a1 dll also.Can any body plese look in to

this....

thanks in advance
Senthil

Answer (score 1):

try to replace assertXXX functions with corresponding verifyXXX functions.
the last one shall not stop the test.
well, at least it doesn't in Selenium IDE scripts.